# Completely disable focus of elements in a parent

Tags: javascript, css, keyboard, focus, blur

Suppose I have a link, which would fade out the entire page when link is clicked. The reason I fade out the page is because a next page is about to load, but it is not loaded yet. I can use `pointer-events: none` which will disable any mouse events until the next page is loaded.

Suppose it was done with the keyboard, I could use the following to prevent double-enter, or to cleanly disable all elements within, for example tab-enter would be disabled this way as well.

```
parent.onkeydown = fals
parent.onkeyup = fals
parent.onkeypress = fals
function fals() {return false}
```

This works well for short loads, but if it takes a long time to load, the user may notice the following difficulties.

- Cannot tab away from the a tag.
- Cannot use several of the keyboard shortcuts which would control the browser.
- Able to tab into the disabled area from the address bar.

Is there a modern and slick way to prevent these 3 problems, other than setting an onfocus=blur for all of the child elements? I do not care about IE today.

Comment: Your first two "problems" don't seem like problems, it's behaving as you've instructed. Aside from that though, why not just unattach the behavior from the link?

Comment: **behaving as instructed** I am not happy with the fact that the first two are possible. I want to allow the user to tab out into either a modal div or address bar for example, and I don't want them to be able to tab back. **why not just unattach behavior from the link** There are multiple links and buttons. I am keenly aware I can just add handlers to the links to take care of this (setting disabled=true, href=null) I was hoping there would be a way to just apply a rule to the parent, this is what I am asking about.

Answer (score 0):

I think the commonly accepted way of dealing with things like what you're talking about is to use Modal's, which is to say when they click that link, you pop up a box that says 'Processing' or something like that, and you create a fullscreen div with a z-index above everything else so the user can't click / interact with anything else on the screen until you're done doing whatever it is you are doing.

See http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals for an example of what i'm talking about.

Comment: That is what I have in mind, I just want to know how to keep from allowing keyboard operations. I could use the example you suggest, but I don't really want to add in another plugin to this page, just for this one thing.

Comment: Oh I see. Well, certainly put focus somewhere in your modal, but if that isn't good enough and you're really worried about them tabbing around and somehow getting back to that link/button they were on, I'd add a check in your submit function that sets/unsets/checks a flag somewhere to ensure that if it's called again before the results come back, it simply ignores it. That'd probably be the most reliable way of ensuring it from the client side.